# Link facebook to existing account / omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

Simple as that, I want to link to an existing user account his facebook profile (giving priority to the email that has originally registered with) in my rails app, using omniauth and devise.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837737/using-omniauth-to-facebook-connect-existing-user-with-different-permissions) but wasn't much helpful to me.

My current structure is [like this one](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview).

Comment: Take a better look at the page you just linked to. In the Google Oauth 2 example, the `find_for_google_oauth2` method does exactly what you want. It first gets the email from the `auth.info.email` hash and then searches for a user with that email with `User.where(:email => email).first`.

Comment: The easiest way is to let the user sign in through his existing account and then let him sign in in Facebook. After sign in in Facebook, you have to add the facebook user id to the current logged in user. Try to solve it and come back for help, if you got stuck.

Answer (score 3):

Below is an example of how I implemented this.  If the user is already signed in, then I call a method that links their account with Facebook.  Otherwise, I go through the same procedure outlined in the [Devise-Omniauth wiki page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview).

```
# users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

def facebook
  if user_signed_in?
    if current_user.link_account_from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
      flash[:notice] = "Account successfully linked"
      redirect_to user_path(current_user) and return
    end
  end

  @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

  if @user.persisted?
    sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
    set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
  else
    session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    redirect_to new_user_registration_url
  end
end

# app/models/user.rb

class << self
  def from_omniauth(auth)
    new_user = where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize
    new_user.email = auth.info.email

    new_user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    new_user.skip_confirmation!
    new_user.save
    new_user
  end
end

def link_account_from_omniauth(auth)
  self.provider = auth.provider
  self.uid = auth.uid
  self.save
end
```

Comment: Might add to your link_account_from_omniauth function:
self.oauth_access_token = auth.credentials.token